# How do I compare elements of an array with a string powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am new to Powershell and I have a question.

```
$status = @(qlist job -jt backup -co s)
Write-Host $status[3]
$status[3] -ceq "Suspended"
```

The answer is

```
 Suspended
False
```

My question is: Why is this comparison false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra space in `$status[3]`

```
" Suspended" -eq "Suspended" 
False
```

you may try:

```
" Suspended" -like "*Suspended*" 
True
```

Parameter `-ceq` means case sensitive equal, so use only if really needed. 
Equivalent for case sensitivity like is `-clike`

P.S. Also another option would be to use the trim method, which will remove the empty spaces: `$status[3].trim() -eq "Suspended"`